# How to compute $\int_{\frac{1-p}{2}}^{\frac{1+p}{2}}x^k(1-x)^kdx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Is there a way to compute 
$$I=\int_{\frac{1-p}{2}}^{\frac{1+p}{2}}x^k(1-x)^kdx$$
for very large positive integer $k\gg 1$ and small $p\in (0,1)$? (one may assume $p$ satisfies $p=\Omega(1/\sqrt{k})$)

I am trying to find a better upper bound on this integral than $p2^{-2k}$. Especially, how far it is from the lower bound $p\Big(\frac{1-p}{2}\Big)^k\Big(\frac{1+p}{2}\Big)^k$?

**PS.**
Is it possible to bound by $2^{-2k}\exp(-\Omega(k^{1/2}))$?

Comment: $x-x^2$ has a maximum at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, so the integral is $I < \frac{p}{2^{2k}}$. Is this a good upper bound?

Comment: @rtybase Sorry, there was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the substitution $x=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{u}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$. Then

$$ I = \frac{1}{2^{2k+1}\sqrt{k}} \int_{-p\sqrt{k}}^{p\sqrt{k}} \left( 1 - \frac{u^2}{k} \right)^k \, \mathrm{d}u. $$

This allows us several conclusions.

1. Using the inequality $\log(1+x) \leq x$, we have

   $$ I \leq \frac{1}{2^{2k+1}\sqrt{k}} \int_{-p\sqrt{k}}^{p\sqrt{k}} \mathrm{e}^{-u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{2^{2k+1}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}} \operatorname{erf}(p\sqrt{k}).  $$
2. From the assumption $p = \Omega(k^{-1/2})$, we have

   $$ I = \frac{1}{2^{2k+1}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}} \operatorname{erf}(p\sqrt{k}) \left( 1 + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{k} \right) \right). $$

Answer (score 2):

Note that:
$$B(z;a,b)=\int_0^zx^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx$$
So your integral can be written as:
$$\int_0^{\frac{1+p}{2}}x^k(1-x)^kdx-\int_0^{\frac{1-p}{2}}x^k(1-x)^kdx
$$$$=B\left(\frac{1+p}{2},k+1,k+1\right)-B\left(\frac{1-p}{2},k+1,k+1\right)$$

Comment: More info can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function